# Javascript Computation using If statement

Tags: javascript

```
 var A = 1, B = 2;
 if(A==B) {A} else {B}  + 1
```

The result of the statement above is 1 and I'm trying to get a 3 returned.  Why does the If statement not return a number?

Comment: `if(A == B) { return A + 1 } else { return B + 1 }`

Comment: **Shorter one:** `return (A === B ? A : B) + 1;`

Comment: `"Why does the If statement not return a number?"` - Why would you expect it to?  `if` doesn't `return` anything.  It's not clear what you're even *trying* to do here.  "returning" is a concept for functions, but there's no function here.  What is this code trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just a side note, but you shouldn't use loose equality in JS.

Comment: **Even shorter one:** `3`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

var A, B;

A = 1;

B = 2 ;

A==B ? A : B+1